# iterating over list containing objects of another class

Tags: java, list, loops, assign

I am studying Java and I have an assignment to do. Here are the requirements.

There are two classes

1. Runner
2. MarathonAdmin

We have to create a runners list which holds the instances of Runner class
and have to assign values to instances `name`, `age` and `agegroup` taken from another *txt file*.
In another part there is requirement that create random numbers between 90 to 180 inclusive and iterate over each runner and assign random number value to runner's time instance.

I am stuck in last part. I am not getting how to iterate over each runner in runners list. I am including code I have done so far.
I need help with `runMarathon()` method whose requirement states

> Write a public method for the `MarathonAdmin` class called `runMarathon()` that takes no arguments and returns no value. The method should iterate over runners, and for each runner generate a random number between 90 and 180 (inclusive) which should be used to set the time (in minutes) for that runner.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import ou.*;
import java.util.Random;
/**
* Write a description of class MarathonAdmin here.
*
* @author (your name)
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class MarathonAdmin
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private List<Runner> runners;
    private String ageGroup;
    private String age;
    private Random randomNumber;
    private String result;
    String ageRunner;
    String ageGrouprunners;
    Scanner lineScanner;
    int ans;
    Runner runnerobj = new Runner();

    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class MarathonAdmin
    */
    public MarathonAdmin()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        runners = new ArrayList<>();

    }    

    /**
    * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
    *
    * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
    * @return     the sum of x and y
    */


    public void   readInRunners()
    {
        String pathName = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
        File aFile = new File(pathName);
        String nameRunner;


        BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = null;
        try
        {
            bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
            String currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();

            while ( currentLine != null)
            {
                lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);

                lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");

                nameRunner = lineScanner.next();

                ageRunner = lineScanner.next();
                ageGrouprunners = result;
                int size = runners.size();

                if (Integer.parseInt(ageRunner) < 18)
                {
                    result = "junior";
                    System.out.println(currentLine +" category" +  " : Junior");

                }

                if (Integer.parseInt(ageRunner) > 55)
                {
                    result = "senior";
                    System.out.println(currentLine +" category"+ " : Senior");
                }

                if (Integer.parseInt(ageRunner) > 18 && Integer.parseInt(ageRunner) < 55)
                {
                    result = "standard";
                    System.out.println(currentLine +" category"+ " : Standard");
                }

                Runner runnerobj = new Runner();
                runnerobj.setName(nameRunner);
                runnerobj.setAgeGroup(ageGrouprunners);
                System.out.println(runnerobj);   //rough test

                runners.add(runnerobj);

                currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception anException)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {
                bufferedFileReader.close();
            }

            catch (Exception anException)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
            }
        }
    }

public void runMarathon()
{
    int size = runners.size();
    for ( int runnersIndex = 0; runnersIndex <= size; runnersIndex ++ )
    {
        this.randomNumber = new Random();
        ans = randomNumber.nextInt(190 - 80 +1 ) + 90 ;
        System.out.println(ans);
        String runnerTime;
        for( String nameRunner :)
        {

        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your code is without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: "Usually 3 spaces per block" - 4 is *much* more common, in my experience.

Comment: @JonSkeet: how can I argue with you? So changed. I also have to add to the original poster that you'll want to cut back on empty lines. One empty line in a row is enough. Any more than that also reduces your code's readability. Again the equation here is: improved code readability and improved clarity of question == improved odds of getting decent answers. Good luck!

Comment: a hovercraft full of eels is a terrifying thought

Comment: your brackets appear screwed up

Comment: Small point: the numbers in your `randomNumber.nextInt` call have a typo in them.

Comment: While asking homework questions is perfectly fine, there are some good guidelines for asking homework questions here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/238586). Summarized, they are: make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first; ask about _specific_ problems with your _existing_ code; make sure your class allows using Q&A for help; don't copy and paste an answer's code without first understanding what it does and how it works.

Comment: If you follow those guidelines, you question will likely get upvoted and answered. If you _don't_, it is liable to get downvoted and maybe even closed. If it does get closed, don't worry: you can still edit your question to improve it. If people think your question deserves to be reopened, it should be—but very occasionally isn't. If you think your question should be reopened, see [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Your call to .nextInt() is not going to give you the range you expect because the calculation is wrong. You also don't need to do a calculation - just provide the upper bound.

The way you've set up your loop with the runnersIdx, all you need to do is access the runner with the index. See the documentation for [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) since that's what you used (`List<Runner>`).

Whenever you're learning a programming language, you'll want to bookmark the documentation website and reference it frequently. The docs for java 7 are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

You may also find the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop in `runMarathon()` function. You'll want to retrieve each runner from your `List` and assign a time.

```
for ( int runnersIndex = 0; runnersIndex <= size; runnersIndex ++ ) {
    this.randomNumber = new Random();
    ans = randomNumber.nextInt(190 - 80 +1 ) + 90 ;

    Runner runner = runners.get(runnersIndex);
    runner.setTime(ans); //make sure you create the getters/setters for this value

}
```